What's wrong with this attempt at a proof that no set of finite cardinality contains itself?
One benefit of including the Axiom of Regularity/Foundation in an axiomatic system is that it can be used to justify that that no set contains itself, at least not in any axiomatic system that includes the Axiom of Regularity/Foundation
The impression I've gotten is that adopting the Axiom of Regularity/Foundation is necessary for showing that even no set of finite cardinality contains itself, and not merely just sufficient to show this to be the case.
If the Axiom of Regularity/Foundation is indeed necessary rather than merely sufficient, then that means there is an error in the following attempt at a proof that no set of finite cardinality contains itself:
Case 1: non-empty sets of finite cardinality greater than 1
Let $A$ be a non-empty set with cardinality $n$
Let $x_i$ be an element of $A$ for $i=1,...,n$, such that each $x_i$ is distinct from every other $x_i$ and the elements are ordered randomly.
While {$x_1, ... , x_n$} is a subset of itself, it is not an element of itself, which can be observed through the lack of such an element
among its elements.
Case 2: non-empty sets of cardinality 1
Let $A$ be a non-empty set with cardinality $1$
Let $x$ be the element of $A$
While {$x$} is a subset of itself, it is not an element of itself, which can be observed through the lack of such an element
among its elements.
Case 3: the empty set
The empty set has no elements, which means that no set can be an element of the empty set

I cannot  understand your nonempty set argument. Why does it "work" if you have a set $x$ with a unique element $x$, $x={x}$? The only element, $x$, is distinct from "every other" element, namely no element. But $x$ is an element of itself. Or take a set ${x,y}$ with $x={x,y}$ and $y\notin y$. Then $x$ and $y$ are different (one is an element of itself, the other is not). But $x$ is an element of itself. How does what you write preclude this? (Also, not every set is finite)

ah yes good point. Updating my question right now. Thanks

Is this LLM generated?

Absolutely not.

It's not really clear to me what you are saying. But your case 2 seems to assert without proof that $x\ne {x}$, or perhaps to assume that because the two expressions are written differently they must have different values, which is not correct.

I do understand now that the Axiom of Foundation is necessary to show that such an $x$ doesn't exist satisfying $x=${$x$}, which my attempt failed to justify

It's necessary in the sense that ZF - regularity does not prove that no set contains itself. It is not necessary in the sense that the axiom "no set contains itself" is strictly weaker than regularity, i.e. it is consistent with ZF - regularity that regularity fails and no set contains itself.
As to your attempt, you've just stated there's "a lack of such an element among its elements" without any argument. What if it is the case that $x=\{x\}$? Then $x\in x$... and $\{x\}\in x$ and $x\in\{x\}$ and $\{\{x\}\}\in x$, and so on (every set referred to in these expressions is equal to $x$). I can logically infer "the presence of those elements amongst the elements" just fine. The argument would have to show there's something contradictory about the premise $x=\{x\},$ and that can't be shown in ZF - regularity.

thanks for helping me understand the issue! I'll take the downvote on the chin as I know I deserved it for not thinking more deeply and carefully.
